# Sylius Product Variants and Attributes

Tags: sylius

In sylius you can add and set attributes for every product. But can you do the same for product variants? We need to have different information per variant and so we are thinking in adding attributes per variant.

If this possible?

Thank you!.

Comment: You could use the Options instead of the Attributes to set different information against the variants. Attributes are solely against the product by the looks